# Resumés for freelancing

Tags: resume, freelancing, self-employment

I'm a professional freelance translator-interpreter, but I've only been working in the field (on a freelance basis) for a few years. I often get asked by agencies to submit a resumé, which they would use to decide whether to send me jobs.

I don't feel the format for the "standard" resumés do justice to what we as freelancers need to represent. As a freelancer, I've translated thousands of texts, and I've done interpretation in dozens of places, including parliament. Submitting a resumé detailing past experience and positions wouldn't give me the right platform to showcase what I've done.

Does anyone here (who is a freelancer as well) share this feeling? Are there alternate formats that you would recommend?

Thanks!
Ilan

Comment: This is a very good question, and I think it will find a good home over at http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

I think what you may want to look at is a [Skills Based Resume](http://blogs.wsj.com/laidoff/2009/03/23/getting-ahead-with-a-skills-based-resume/).  You list the skills you have and the major high points / projects you have worked on and focus more on the skills you have than where you got them.  At the end you do a listing of your work experience with minimal information (Company name, title and dates of employment).  When I was switching into the IT field it was the format I used when my work experience did not show my skills I had acquired from my own study and tinkering.

There may be some better formats out there but having personally used the Skills Based resume it is the only one I can say for sure can have some success.

Comment: In a case such as the OP's I could see listing the OP's skills and then adding a number of high-profile examples of working experience to support that skill and mentioning in some form that the OP has many more examples available on request. This way the potential employer knows that you've got plenty of experience, they have a few eye-catching examples and they know that you're well experienced.
In addition, I would add a paragraph in the beginning of the resumé with a short description of myself, where I would mention the multitude of experience.